# Why is feDropShadow poorly supported in non-browsers and leads to things disappear?

Tags: svg, imagemagick, inkscape

The following happens to me on a regular basis when trying to write SVGs manually.

- I perform a web search for "svg drop shadow", and amongst the first hits is the [MDN example on `feDropShadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feDropShadow), which feels a decent reference.
- I copy/paste that example into a local `.svg` file.
- When I look at this local `.svg` with various document viewers it shows as a **blank white page** -- not at all what the example is supposed to look like, and I'm very confused.

The source of the example looks like that:

```xml
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="0.2" dy="0.4" stdDeviation="0.2" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="shadow2">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="0.5" flood-color="cyan" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="shadow3">
      <feDropShadow
        dx="-0.8"
        dy="-0.8"
        stdDeviation="0"
        flood-color="pink"
        flood-opacity="0.5" />
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="5" cy="50%" r="4" style="fill:pink; filter:url(#shadow);" />

  <circle cx="15" cy="50%" r="4" style="fill:pink; filter:url(#shadow2);" />

  <circle cx="25" cy="50%" r="4" style="fill:pink; filter:url(#shadow3);" />
</svg>
```

and should look like this:

[image]

I'm a Linux user and the example renders as a blank white page in basically all my local tooling including:

- All my image viewers I tried including `eog` (Ubuntu default image viewer) and `geeqie`.
- Inkspace
- ImageMagick's `convert`

What adds to my confusion is that they don't render anything all, i.e., they seem to even ignore the "fill" as a result of `feDropShadow` being there. For instance, this is what I see in Inkscape (I've selected the elements to show that they are there in principle, just not rendering at all):

[image]

I can also use Inkscapes filter editor and remove the `feDropShadow` filters, which makes the elements appear again:

[image]

On the other hand the file **does** render correctly in any browser I tried. Also, the [browser support matrix on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feDropShadow#browser_compatibility) notes that most browsers have added support ~10 years ago, suggesting that it is not a brand new feature of the SVG standard.

I'm wondering why this is the case.

- Is there something unusual about the MDN example that could explain why it only works in browsers, or is it just a coincidence that all my local renderers simply don't support `feDropShadow`?
- Is it expected behavior that the renderers do to not show the elements at all if they don't support a certain filter, or is this yet another coincidence that they all end up showing a blank page?

(I couldn't identify the underlying rendering engine for all of them, so it also may come down to different tools simply using the same underlying renderer, but if I remember correctly at least Inkscape and ImageMagick have different renderers...)

Comment: Because feDropShadow is newer than other filters. Other SVG filters come from SVG 1.1, drop shadow comes from a newer filters specification. SVG 1.1 said don't render unsupported features, SVG 2 says ignore unsupported features and render as if they didn't exist.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/4534

Comment: As for eog and geeqie: feDropShadow is implemented in `librsvg` in version [2.56](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg/-/milestones/55#tab-issues), which is part of Gnome 44. Ubuntu has version [2.54.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/librsvg2-2) in the current Ubuntu Kinetic (22.10) repository.

Comment: Correction: the current Ubuntu version is Mantic (23.10), but the librsvg version is **still** at [2.54.7+dfsg-2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/librsvg2-2)